# Does my method work for adding a new integer before the last value in a linked list?

Tags: java, hyperlink

I'm not sure how to test my method, any advice would be appreciated. I wrote a quick code and I'm just wondering, does it seem to look like it would work?

---

this is the question:

Assuming an IntNode class defined like this:

```
  public class IntNode {
     public int data;
     public IntNode next;
     public IntNode(int data, IntNode next) {
         this.data = data; this.next = next;
     }
     public String toString() {
         return data + "";
  }
```

Implement a method that will add a new integer before the last value in the linked list whose first node is pointed to by front. (In other words, the added integer will become the second-to-last item in the resulting linked list.) The method should return a pointer/reference to the front node of the resulting linked list. If the input linked list is empty, the method should return null, without doing anything.

```
public static IntNode addBeforeLast(IntNode front, int item) {
      /* COMPLETE THIS METHOD */
}
```

---

This is the code I wrote! p.s. I'm just reviewing for an exam!

```
public class testing {

public static IntNode addBeforeLast(IntNode front, int item) {
    /* COMPLETE THIS METHOD */
    IntNode prev=front; IntNode ptr=front;
    if (front==null) {
        System.out.println("List is Empty!");
        return front; 

    }

    while (ptr.next!=null){
        prev=prev.next;
        ptr=ptr.next.next;
    }
    IntNode temp= new IntNode (item, front);
    prev.next=temp;
    temp.next=ptr;
    return front;   
}
```